# my sum output didnt display 42 but instead "q"

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, emu8086

> i try to run the emu8086 and try to get the output 42 after of sum by array 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, but instead it shows "q", im using looping sum one bye one the array

```
.model small

.stack 100

.data

byteList db 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12

sum db ?  

.code
main proc

mov ax,@data 

mov ds,ax
  
mov cx, 6  
mov si, 0

L1:

add al, byteList[si]
inc si
   
loop l1 

mov sum, al

    mov ah,02h    
    mov dl,sum 
    add dl, 48
    int 21h
 
  
         
 end:   mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

 main endp
end main
```

Comment: What ASCII character is `42 + '0'`?  That simplified version only works for single-digit numbers.  `"42"` is a 2-byte string of digits.

Comment: " * ", how do i output 2 byte string of digits?, if i remove "add dl, 48" the output goes "B"

Comment: Look at the linked duplicate at the top of the question.